# Zapier run Python not getting all product line items names

Tags: python, google-sheets, shopify, zapier

Shopify to google-sheets via zapier to get new paid order customer address, email, phone and product purchased information.  The problem is, when there is more than one item in the purchase I only get the first product retrieved.

```
def combine_pairings(listing):
    out = []
    for index, val in enumerate(listing):
        if index % 2:
            continue
        out.append("{} {}".format(val, listing[index+1]))
    return out

def get_index(lst, index):
    try:
        return lst[index]
    except:
        return 'empty'

units = input['units'].split(',')
products = input['product'].split(',')
time = combine_pairings(input.get('time', '').split(','))

output = []

for index, product in enumerate(products):
    output.append({
        'units': get_index(units, index),
        'product': product,
        'phone': input['phone'],
        'customer_note': input.get('customer_note', ''),
        'address': input['address'],
        'status': input['status'],
        'customerlastname': input['customerlastname'],
        'customerfirstname': input['customerfirstname'],
        'email': input['email'],
        'time': get_index(time, index)
    })

return output
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your code?  Refer to [ask].

Comment: please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41389308/edit) and post code as code block instead of image, paste into question then highlight and click the `{}` button.

Comment: you also need to show more context for this code, `input` is clearly not referring to the builtin function and you have a return statement outside of any function definition which is nonsense.

Comment: sorry about my sloppy post. hopefully the changes i made are to your preference? thanks, Jamie

Comment: @Jamie If you're still having issues with this give me a shout. There are ways to fix it, but you'll have to create another Python Step. Over the past month I've been struggling to optimize use of Zapier, a lot of times I have to resort to calling APIs separately with Python code steps. Zapier, just doesn't offer the flexibility advanced users need with their integrations. Parsing zapier strings can be infuriating, but I can help!